# Can someone please explain why is this modulo calculated here?

Tags: c, algorithm

I am trying to solve a programming problem Array rotation to the right.
So given an array of length and an integer value K, I am supposed to rotate it to the right by K times.
I tried understanding the algorithm and came up with the following solution:

```
void reverse(int *nums, int start, int end)
{
    while(start<end)
    {
        int temp = nums[start];
        nums[start] = nums[end];
        nums[end] = temp;
        start++;
        end--;
    }
}
void rotate(int* nums, int numsSize, int k) {
    k = k % numsSize;
    if(numsSize > 1)
    {
    reverse(nums, 0, (numsSize - k - 1));
    reverse(nums, numsSize - k, numsSize - 1);
    reverse(nums, 0, numsSize - 1);    
    }
    else
        *nums = *nums;

}
```

In the above solution, I am reversing the array 3 times so that it gets rotated. First reversal is 0, length - K, 2nd reversal is length - k, length and third the entire array.

But my question is, if I don't add this line
`k = k%numsSize`, I get an error for k > numsSize.
Why is it?

I followed this youtube link [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EpP6YuqzHe8)but he didn't mention anything about that modulo operation as well.

Thanks

Comment: You get a subscript out of bounds if you don't ensure it is in bounds with the modulo operation.  Or you're calling rotate incorrectly, with a `k` that is out of bounds.  It is a bit surprising that you managed to add the operation and yet don't understand why you added it.  Another way to understand it, if you have an array of 12 items, say, and you rotate it by 34 places, the result is the same as rotating it by 10 places (34 % 12 == 10).

Comment: Aside from algorithmic considerations, if you rotate an array by an integer multiple of its element count then you get back the original array.  The modulo operation in your code computes how far you're going past such a rotation.

Comment: Basically it rotates the index so it never goes out of bonds. If size is 100, valid indexes are from 0 to 99, if you try to access index 100 it goes back to 0, if you try to access 101 it goes to 1 and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with k>numsSize means  numsSize - k is negative you call your reverse function with a negative number as an index you try to access the array at an out of bound address * program crashes *

Comment: so, how do I fix it?

Comment: fix what ? i suppose it works if you leave the modulo right? your question was why you have to keep it .. look for example for an array of size 8 if you do a rotation by 9 is like rotating by 1 ? which is 9%8 =1

Comment: By fix I mean, should I have the if condition? I don't think it is needed since I am doing the modulo operation.

Comment: Well the if checks if there is one element no need to rotate it anyway bcz rotating 1  element array is useless  you can leave it so it doesn't go to the reverse  and do extra work